# List all Validation objects in a sheet with Excel Interop without iterate on each cell

Tags: c#, excel, performance, validation, excel-interop

I'd like to know if it is possible to **list** all *Excel.Validation* objects of a specific sheet without iterate on each cell.

Iterate on each cell takes to much time.

Sometimes, a validation constraint is applied on big range (which is not named). I would like :

1. quickly list all thoses constraints objects
2. change the constraints (Validation.Formula1)

Is it possible without iterate on each cell ?
This code takes too much time :

```
foreach (Excel.Range cell in mySheet.UsedRange)
{
   string newFormula1 = ...;
   cell.Validation.Modify(Formula1: newFormula1);
}
```

Actually, I am looking for `mysheet.ValidationList` objects.

Thanks.